# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'-arima time series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

trying to plot a 2-d table but getting the error

my table has 2 columns only and code is:

```
Combined = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['Revenue_mth'], index_col = ['Revenue_mth'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Revenue amount')
plt.plot(Combined)
```

Comment: Please post a few lines of your input (`file_path`) and add the `pandas` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`Combined` is the data frame, you have to specify the columns in your plot command.

```
 Combined = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['Revenue_mth'], 
                        index_col = ['Revenue_mth'])
 plt.xlabel('Date')
 plt.ylabel('Revenue amount')
 plt.plot(Combined['Revenue_mth'],Combined['Column 2'])
 plt.show()
```

where 'Column 2' is the name of the header of your other column.